# Usage of Facebook's (Commerce Platform) - Catalog and Inventory Batch API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

My main desired usecase is to manage the catalog and inventory of a Facebook Shop via API usage (even though I'm not yet a FB developer).

From this documentation I get that it is completely posssible: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/catalog/batch-api

Nevertheless I have a couple of doubts. The documentation above is part of the facebook's "commerce platform" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform), which according to the following links, seems to be in "closed beta accessed only by invitation".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/setup/api-setup
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/project-guide

So my first question is: **Is the Catalog and Inventory Batch API really "locked" behind the closed beta status?** I'm having this doubt because it is unclear to me that the whole commerce platform is locked behind the closed beta (instead of just parts of it) - As for example the case of the Order Management API (belonging also to the commerce platform) which explicitly says it is in a closed beta status (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/order-management/using-api).

My second doubt is a more fundamental question regarding general Facebook development. It seems from way the commerce documentation is structured (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/app-dashboard), that the usage of the commerce API libraries (but perhaps all facebook development libraries?), need to be used within the context of a "Facebook APP" (which seems to be either a smatphone app, a webapp or other) ... **Is this really true? is every usage of any of FB's development libraries intended to run within a "Facebook APP"?**

As explained before, I'm just interested in importing catalog articles into a Facebook Shop programmatically via an API - Being forced to create some sort of "Facebook App" just for that seems absurd.

Any clarification on those points or further references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

****EDIT: the 2nd question has been answered by CBroe's comment bellow. The only remaining question is the 1st one regarding the Catalog Batch API being in closed beta status (or not).****

Comment: “App” does not mean a specific piece of _software_, in this context. You need an app id as the very basis of being able to communicate with the API.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification CBroe, your feedback is greatly appreciated.